# Какую падежную форму выбрать?

Tags: падежи

1. Учителя ожидали именно такого ответа.
2. Учителя ожидали именно такой ответ.

Как определить, какая форма является наиболее актуальной?

Comment: Если вам нужно их непременно различить, то можно привести такой пример: Учителя ожидали именно этот ответ. Учителя ожидали именно такого ответа.  "Этот ответ" – полная определенность, а "такой ответ" допускает варианты.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошо сказано, но "именно" не очень стыкуется с "такого", потому что "именно" (*как раз; конкретно*) — это определённость. Так что с "именно" нужен винительный.

Comment: Так в задании слово "именно" присутствует в обоих предложениях, а местоимение "такой" выделяет не один ответ, а обозначает вид ответа по основному содержанию.

Comment: @Sharon "Именно такой" сопоставимо с "именно этот", из-за "именно", которое указывает на конкретику.

Comment: Нет, они разные. Даже в Грамматике сказано, что союзное слово "такой" качественно-типизирующее (в разделе про СПП с придаточными определительными).

Comment: "Такой" и "этот" безусловно разные, но "именно" их очень сближает.

Comment: Спасибо за обсуждение. Сейчас стало намного понятнее.